# Why is parallel execution policy so slow

Tags: c++, c++17

I tried using the following 2 versions of my function:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto mult(T const& a, U const& b) {
  return std::transform_reduce(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0.);
  //return std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par, a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0.);
}
```

I am calling this function with 2 `std::array`s The second version (commented out above) runs ~40x *slower* than the first one. I am using VS2019 (16.3.1), compiling on Release.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You were right.  The third iterator is also used only for reading so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver ranging from a few dozen to ~1000 (the majorit), but being called on many thousands of datasets

Comment: Your data sets are pretty small.  Spinning up threads cost time and resources and it may just be that extra overhead far outweighs any benefit you'd get from parallelizing.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried with datasets of 10000 with similar (only ~10x slower) results

Comment: Hmm, that should be large enough to make difference.  [I tried my own test](https://godbolt.org/z/Du8S3A) with even larger input and the non parallel one is always faster.  [I also tested gcc(https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zbty6imqCyOBnZNO) and it gives similar results for large data sets.  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @NathanOliver Try `par_unseq` instead of `par` to enable vectorization and you'll see a substantial improvement in the parallel version. Anyway, these numeric algorithms for trivial types are usually very fast and often it is not worth parallelizing them unless the input is extremelly large.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, i read the reference later, `transform_reduce` with no user-specified functional objects does a dot product.

Comment: The questioner @Baruch could have profiled the fast and slow versions and included profiling results in the post. This would reduce the amount of pure speculation from the question responders.